# how can I stop media scanning?

Tags: media-scanner

I have a LG L7 mobile. From 2 days ago I have a serious problem with scanning media files. I turn on my mobile and scanning media files started scanning. after that scanning media files completed it started again and again and until know it is scanning. I do not know is it a hardware or software problem? what I have to do? please help me.

Answer (score 2):

This can often be caused by filesystem corruption on the SD card. The SD card might appear to work normally if you don't access the corrupted parts of the filesystem, but since the media scanner reads the whole filesystem, it's much more likely to get stuck on a corrupted file or directory.

Try removing the SD card and using a card reader on your PC to check the filesystem (e.g. with scandisk or fsck).